# javascript : window.location.href inside a "if"

Tags: javascript, events, if-statement, keycode, window.location

I am a total newby in javascript and I am stuck with a problem.

Everything is happening within this "body" :

```
<body onKeyDown="myFunction(event);">
```

This code works : when I press escape on the page, there is a popup with 27. When I press another key, nothing happens. This is what I wanted.

```
Key_ESC = 27;
function myFunction(event) {
    if ( event.keyCode == 27 ){
        alert(event.keyCode);
    }
}
```

This code works : When I press any key, I go to next page. This is what I wanted.

```
Key_ESC = 27; 
function myFunction(event) {
        window.location.href=\"$INDEX/image`expr $compteur + 1`.html\";
}
```

But this one doesn't work : when I press any key nothing happens. I thought pressing escape would make a change of page (just like without the "if". It is not the case.

```
Key_ESC = 27;
function myFunction(event) {
    if ( event.keyCode == 27 ){
        window.location.href=\"$INDEX/image`expr $compteur + 1`.html\";
    }
}
```

Could any one explain to me why "window.location" doesn't work inside a "if" ? What did I do wrong ? I really have no idea at all....

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is with the `\\`?

Comment: It's because it is inside a echo "..." in a script shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to call event.preventDefault

also, in JS just do:

```
window.onload = function ()
{

Key_ESC=27;
Key_LEFT=37;

document
.   event = 
    {   preventDefault: function( e )
        {   e.preventDefault?e.preventDefault():e.returnValue=false;
        }
    }
;
document.body
.   onkeyup = function nextPage ( e )
    {   
        switch
        (   e.keyCode
        )   {   case Key_ESC
                :   document.event.preventDefault(e);
                    window.location.href=URL_NEXT;
                case Key_LEFT
                :   document.event.preventDefault(e);
                    window.location.href=URL_PREV;
            } 
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't remember the cross-browser version let me look it up.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't really understand your answer.

Comment: When I said it worked, it was just for what you had published at that time :

Comment: Key_ESC = 27;
function myFunction(event) {
    if ( event.keyCode == Key_ESC ){
        event.preventDefault();window.location.href=\"$INDEX/image`expr $compteur + 1`.html\";
    }
}

Comment: I don't konw what to do with the code you gave me, I put it instead of the function myfunction?     And I remove the onKeyDown <body> ?   I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Yeah. That's right. I just tested it in my browser, and you just have to replace URL_NEXT.

Comment: oh yeah. window.onload. Wrap it in window.onload = function(){} or put your <script> towards the </body> so it fires after DOM loads

Comment: Thanks! It works at the end just before </body>. But it doesn't work if I had a second key in the case. For instance Key_ESC for one link, and Key_Arrow_Left for another link. I think I can't put "event.preventDefault" inside every case, no?

Comment: Unfortunately, that just depends on what the key means to the browser. You could put `document.event.preventDefault(e)`  in any `case` or just move it to above the `switch` if that happens to be best. (Also, make sure you `break;` each `case`.)

Comment: You're right. Let me fix it. It's onkeydown or onkeyup you need for arrows.

Comment: Changing onkeydown into onkeyup didn't work for me. (i changed the links of course, and i added the breaks). I tried with  document.event.preventDefault(e) above the switch, or in any case. Are you sure it should work like this?  Nothing happens.

Comment: Hmm. I'm sorry. I don't know. It's working for me. Nothing's really going on here. It's just a switch inside of an event callback. Wonder what it could be.

Comment: It was totally my fault, sorry, it was a parenthesis.......    Thank you so much for your time, my gallery works perfectly now :)

Answer (score 1):

some time i can help

```
function myFunction(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 27){
        window.location.href="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/INDEX/imagename.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It also work!  How to do now if I want to put another action for another key (with a case or two if for instance) ? I tried but it only give me the second action if press the first or the second key.